# How to customize fontsizeselect for TinyMCE in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, font-size

I am trying to return a custom list of font sizes without the use of a plugin for Wordpress. The function I am trying to use currently is below. I have used similar functions to customize the color picker and the format select, but not having any luck with this one. Any help is appreciated.

```
function mycustom_change_tinymce_fontsize( $init ) {
    $custom_sizes = '"14pt", "18pt"';
    $init['fontsize_formats'] = '['.$custom_sizes.']';
    return $init;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mycustom_change_tinymce_fontsize');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatted value is not correct; just follow the below one:

```
function mycustom_change_tinymce_fontsize( $init ) {
    //$init['fontsize_formats'] = "10px 11px 12px 13px 14px 15px 16px 17px 18px 19px 20px 21px 22px 23px 24px 25px 26px 27px 28px 29px 30px 32px";
    $init['fontsize_formats'] = "14pt 18pt";
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mycustom_change_tinymce_fontsize', 12); //-->somewhat important '12', at least more than 10 to keep your changes;
```